# Facebook JavaScript API: run a line of code once asynch calls are completed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, asynchronous

I have a piece of code which makes multiple nested calls to FB.api to retrieve certain information. Eventually, it creates an object called "myfriends" and stores my desired information in that object.

What I want to do is to use that object, after it is filled in with data (i.e. after all asynch calls are done), to run something else. In other words, I need a way for my code to know that those calls are complete. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using callback functions. The other problem I had was that my inner API call was in a loop; I ended up using an asynchronous looping function. This combination solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

call 'myfriends' after async request has completed.

Example:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
  // Use 'myfriends' object here
});
```

Comment: It is not possible, because I have nested calls. It is like 
[this](http://pastebin.com/TC0X8yf9) and when I try to use the object inside the outer api call (after the inner api call), it's content is not yet set by the inner call.